# How to autocomplete EditText with website suggestion?

Tags: java, android

I'm actually developing an Android app that saves and lists websites according to the user requests, and navigate on them in a WebView.
I already performed the navigation after the user input the websites.

Considering the fact that the user may incorrectly insert the URL, I would like to provide suggestion in the EditText for the proper URL to input (as the browser do

Is there a way to perform it?

Many thanks in advance for the help!